# Starting a coroutine from a child scope on the parents context

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In my app I have nested coroutine scopes. In some cases I want to be able to start a coroutine that will run in the background and not block the current coroutineScope.

```
runBlocking {
    coroutineScope {
        launch() {
            delay(500)
            println("3")
        }
    }
    coroutineScope {
        launch {
            println("2")
        }
    }
}
```

I want this to print
1
2
3
Currently it prints
1
3
2
This is because coroutineScope suspends waiting for the launch with a 500ms delay to finish before running the second coroutineScope. I know I can do this

```
runBlocking {
    val parentContext = coroutineContext
    coroutineScope {
        launch(parentContext) {
            delay(500)
            println("3")
        }
    }
    coroutineScope {
        launch {
            println("2")
        }
    }
}
```

but in some cases I have coroutineScope nested multiple layers deep and I don't want to pass around the parentContext if I can avoid it. GlobalScope.launch also works, but Kotlin warns away from using GlobalScope for tasks that take any significant resources.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you're going to do this -- and you usually shouldn't -- you should create, for yourself, a `backgroundScope` you can use.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Why do you say you usually shouldn't? In my case, it seems to make my api faster and cleaner. Wouldn't you still need to pass a background scope around?

Comment: Yes, you would need to have access to the background scope, which may involve some passing it around.  But in general, violating structured concurrency -- calling `scope.launch` for any scope but the local `this` -- should be done only when necessary, including for performance reasons.

Comment: In your first example above, you could remove the outer `coroutineScope` from around the first `launch` call to achieve this without needing a separate background scope. There are maybe more complicated situations where you might have to create a background scope and pass it around, but in most cases it is likely you can redesign to avoid the need for that so you can keep the robustness of structured concurrency. By the way, that last `delay(600)` is unnecessary, and it makes me wonder if you didn't realize a parent coroutine waits for its children to complete, leading to your question here.

Comment: Why do you use `coroutineScope` if you don't want to group executions of related coroutines? Do you maybe have your code split into multiple suspend functions?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an easy way to spawn coroutines and forget about them without waiting for them to complete without passing coroutine scopes around. Put this code at base level in any file:

```kotlin
val backgroundScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob())

inline fun doInBackground(crossinline block: () -> Unit) {
    backgroundScope.launch {
        block.invoke()
    }
}
```

then you can import the function in any other file and call `doInBackground { println("Hello World") }` from anywhere. It's like our own secret GlobalScope.